# Set the stroke color for a UISwitch when it's on?

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, uiswitch

I have a UISwitch that needs to have the same style when it's on as when it's off. The only difference would be where the little circle is.

It looks like this when it's off:

[image]

… which is good. But when I turn it on, the stroke disappears:

[image]

How do I make it keep the stroke when it's on? If that isn't possible, can I at least make it tinted when it's off and not just when it's on?

Comment: How about setting the "On Tint" color to white to match the border?

Comment: @LyndseyScott setting the tint color would also change the background color so it would not look the same when ON

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple may reject your app for not showing a different color for the On state, however I believe this is what you're wanting: This will show the 'stroke' for each state now.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UISwitch *theSwitch;

self.theSwitch.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:229.0/255.0 green:229.0/255.0 blue:229.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
self.theSwitch.layer.borderWidth = 1.5;
self.theSwitch.layer.cornerRadius = 31.0/2.0;
```

Results:

[image]
[image]

Comment: @LyndseyScott nope, not required

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. I'll also look at the layer property next time I want to customize something.