# Swift -How to change the color of the curve on a UISwitch control

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch

How can I change the color of the curve that follows a `UISwitch` control? I tried changing the borderColor but that's tied to the frame.

This is a sample photo from another question. I want to toggle the color of the silver curve in this photo (not the round button and not the orange background)

[image]

I tried these 2 properties but the `.layer.borderWidth = 2.0` and `.layer.cornerRadius = 15` **changes the frame** and not the curve

When it's *on* I want the curve to be `.clear` and when it's *off* I want it to be `.red`

```
lazy var switchControl: UISwitch = {
    let switchControl = UISwitch()
    switchControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchValueDidChange(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
}()

@objc func switchValueDidChange(_ sender: UISwitch) {

    if (sender.isOn == true) {

        sender.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor // this doesn't work

    } else {

        sender.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor // this doesn't work
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope you already checked this link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/24896079/3683408 - cause seems you have attached same switch image. So have you need to set missing items border width and corner radius property on the above your answer

Comment: @Ram no you are wrong, I didn't get the picture from there, I got it from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48404617/changing-background-colour-but-keeping-tint-for-uiswitch-on-state -those properties have nothing to do with the curve, those are for the frame –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believed this doesn't possible without some hacking tips of SDK. But I am proposing to create your own such control using an image.

Answer (score 2):

Yes as iChirag said this can not be done as of now using the built-in `UISwitch`.

As to why it's not possible, it's hard to say with certainty. My guess would be that it's because Apple encourages using a limited color palette in their [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/color/). The main goal of using colors in an iOS app is basically to communicate information, help the user differentiate separate parts of the UI at a glance or to call attention to user actions. Maybe they think that setting a custom color for the curve of a `UISwitch` is outside of these purposes.

With that said, it's fairly easy to build your own custom `UISwitch` if you need this appearance. Here is a tutorial to get you started, hope this helps:

[Make custom UISwitch (Part 1)](https://medium.com/@factoryhr/making-custom-uiswitch-part-1-cc3ab9c0b05b)

Comment: Thanks. I choose iChirag’s as the accepted answer because he said it first but I upvoted yours for the detailed answer and link 

Answer (score 1):

Change Tint color of UISwitch

mSwitch.tintColor = offColor// Custom color